Intrinsic band gap vs work function of doped semiconductors
I'm confused about this question on doped semiconductors:

Question: Photoelectrons with a maximum energy of $\ 0.5$ eV are observed when light of wavelength
$500$ nm is incident on a heavily n-doped semiconductor. Calculate the work
function. When the experiment is repeated with a heavily p-doped semiconductor
made of the same material, a wavelength of $400$ nm is required to observe the same
maximum energy. Estimate the intrinsic band gap of the semiconductor.
Answers: $2$ eV, $\ 0.6$ eV

I calculated the correct answer of $\ 2$ eV for the work function of the $500$ nm photons.
I then calculated the work function for the $400$ nm photons to be $\ 2.6$ eV. From here, I was unsure how to get to the intrinsic band gap. However, the correct answer was given to be $\ 0.6$ eV, so I'm guessing that you just subtract the above work functions from each other.
But this is where I'm confused. Why does subtracting the 2 work functions from each other give the intrinsic band gap? Shouldn't the work functions of doped semiconductors be less than the intrinsic band gap?

Well, where are the electrons coming from in each case?

As you said, in a heavily n-doped semiconductor, the Fermi level $E_F$  is close to or a little above the conduction band edge $E_C$, but not very much. Conversely, in a heavily p-doped semiconductor, the Fermi level $E_F$ is close to, or a little below the valence band edge $E_V$. Thus, a rough estimate of the band gap is $E_G=E_C-E_V$, the difference of the observed work functions. Actually, your are right, the difference of the work functions should be a little bit larger than the band gap (disregarding effects like the band gap narrowing at high doping levels).

That makes sense. You made me realise there was a crucial bit that I was misunderstanding but I get it now, thank you!
